# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: laravel

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para gestionar ligas de pádel. Estoy utilizando Laravel y Filament. La tabla de partidos es la siguiente:

```
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('liga_id')->references('id')->on('ligas');
        $table->foreignId('local_team_id')->references('id')->on('equipos');
        $table->foreignId('visitante_team_id')->references('id')->on('equipos'); 
        $table->unique(['liga_id', 'local_team_id','visitante_team_id']);                    
        $table->foreignId('pista_id')->constrained();
```

He establecido que para que no se pueda crear un partido duplicado la combinación de los tres campos a la vez 'liga_id','local_team_id' y 'visitante_team_id' debe ser UNIQUE. Es decir, el equipo A no puede volver a jugar con el equipo B en la misma liga. Esto funciona correctamente, ya que si esto ocurre obtengo el siguiente mensaje de error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para obtener en vez de la página de error de Laravel un alert o similar que me devuelva al formulario.

El formulario que utilizo está creado con Filament y es el siguiente:

```
class PartidoResource extends Resource
{
    protected static ?string $model = Partido::class;

    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-collection';

    public $nombre;
 

    public static function form(Form $form): Form
       {

        return $form
            ->schema([
                Card::make()->schema([                    
                    Select::make('liga_id')
                        ->label('Liga')
                        ->options(Liga::where('en_marcha', 'false')->pluck('nombre', 'id'))
                        ->searchable()->required(),
                    Select::make('local_team_id')->reactive()
                        ->label('Equipo Local')
                        ->options(function (Closure $get) {
                            return Equipo::where('id', '!=', $get('visitante_team_id'))->pluck('nombre', 'id');
                        })
                        ->searchable()->required(),
                    Select::make('visitante_team_id')->reactive()
                        ->label('Equipo visitante')
                        ->options(function (Closure $get) {
                            return Equipo::where('id', '!=', $get('local_team_id'))->pluck('nombre', 'id');
                        })
                        ->searchable()->required(),                        

                    Select::make('pista_id')
                        ->label('Pista')
                        ->options(Pista::all()->pluck('nombre', 'id'))
                        ->searchable()->required(),
                ]),
                

                Card::make()->schema([
                    Toggle::make('jugado')
                ])

            ]);
        }
        
    
    
    
    public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->columns([
                //
            ])
            ->filters([])
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
            ]);
    }

    public static function getRelations(): array
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }

    public static function getPages(): array
    {
        return [
            'index' => Pages\ListPartidos::route('/'),
            'create' => Pages\CreatePartido::route('/create'),
            'edit' => Pages\EditPartido::route('/{record}/edit'),
        ];
    }

    
}
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Podrías validar eso haciendo una consulta antes de guardar, si ya existe el registro que se quiere insertar, regresas el mensaje que quieres mostrar

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.